# Rotating videos with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rotation, video-processing

I have been trying to figure out how to rotate videos with FFmpeg. I am working with iPhone videos taken in portrait mode. I know how to determine the current degrees of rotation using [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) (excellent library, btw) but I'm stuck on FFmpeg now.

From what I've read, what you need to use is a **vfilter** option. According to what I see, it should look like this:

```
ffmpeg -vfilters "rotate=90" -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

However, I can't get this to work. First, **-vfilters** doesn't exist anymore, it's now just **-vf**. Second, I get this error:

```
No such filter: 'rotate'
Error opening filters!
```

As far as I know, I have an all-options-on build of FFmpeg. Running ***ffmpeg -filters*** shows this:

```
Filters:
anull            Pass the source unchanged to the output.
aspect           Set the frame aspect ratio.
crop             Crop the input video to x:y:width:height.
fifo             Buffer input images and send them when they are requested.
format           Convert the input video to one of the specified pixel formats.
hflip            Horizontally flip the input video.
noformat         Force libavfilter not to use any of the specified pixel formats
 for the input to the next filter.
null             Pass the source unchanged to the output.
pad              Pad input image to width:height[:x:y[:color]] (default x and y:
 0, default color: black).
pixdesctest      Test pixel format definitions.
pixelaspect      Set the pixel aspect ratio.
scale            Scale the input video to width:height size and/or convert the i
mage format.
slicify          Pass the images of input video on to next video filter as multi
ple slices.
unsharp          Sharpen or blur the input video.
vflip            Flip the input video vertically.
buffer           Buffer video frames, and make them accessible to the filterchai
n.
color            Provide an uniformly colored input, syntax is: [color[:size[:ra
te]]]
nullsrc          Null video source, never return images.
nullsink         Do absolutely nothing with the input video.
```

Having the options for **vflip** and **hflip** are great and all, but they just won't get me where I need to go. I need to the ability to rotate videos 90 degrees at the very least. 270 degrees would be an excellent option to have as well. Where have the rotate options gone?

Comment: Updated my answer. It looks like that filter was just added last month to source.

Comment: For anyone searching for a 180 degree rotation: `-vf "vflip,hflip"`

Comment: I am wondering, if this can be achieved without decoding and then re-encoding the video -- the way jpegtran can losslessly rotate JPEG images...

Comment: I believe that a lot of devices support some kind of embedded rotation value. They will rotate (losslessly) automatically when decoding, but the support isn't universal. That was the problem I was trying to avoid when asking this question originally.

Comment: See here for rotation flag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335073/can-i-set-rotation-field-for-a-video-stream-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Also see the detailed answer at [How to flip a video 180° (vertical/upside down) with FFmpeg?](http://superuser.com/a/578329/110524) **Don't forget to reset any existing rotation metadata** (see link).

Comment: I just uploaded a 180° rotated video  with "transpose=1,transpose=1" to vimeo. Even though I can play back the rotated video, it was rejected by vimeo. @OrangeDog's approach `-vf "vflip,hflip"` works like a charm.

Comment: This question is way off-topic for SO now, and there's a nearly identical one [on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/578321/how-to-rotate-a-video-180-with-ffmpeg).

Comment: Also see this: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/23245/23954 my video was rotated 180° and I could not understand why.

Comment: This was referenced in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423875/my-post-keeps-getting-downvoted-for-no-obvious-reason) (in comments). The meta question references Stack Overflow question *[Mix multiple audios into one with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792819/mix-multiple-audios-into-one-with-ffmpeg)*.

Comment: A similar question on Super User: *[How can I rotate a video 180° with FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/578321/how-can-i-rotate-a-video-180-with-ffmpeg)*

Answer (score 937, accepted):

Rotate 90 clockwise:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf "transpose=1" out.mov
```

For the transpose parameter you can pass:

```
0 = 90° counterclockwise and vertical flip (default)
1 = 90° clockwise
2 = 90° counterclockwise
3 = 90° clockwise and vertical flip
```

Use `-vf "transpose=2,transpose=2"` for 180 degrees.

Make sure you use a recent FFmpeg version [from here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) (a static build will work fine).

**Note that this will re-encode the audio and video parts**. You can usually copy the audio without touching it, by using `-c:a copy`. To change the video quality, set the bitrate (for example with `-b:v 1M`) or have a look at the [H.264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) if you want VBR options.

A solution is also to use this [convenience script](https://github.com/meduz/photoscripts/blob/master/rotate_video.py).

Comment: The video will still have the orientation information so now the video will be miss corrected on the iphone.

Comment: So in order to rotate 180 degrees I would have to convert twice with "transpose=1"? I don't want the mirroring effect from using hflip.

Comment: When I use this command, I get a **low quality video output**, unless -- as I've just discovered -- I use this parameter as well: `-vcodec libx264`. But it would be great if I didn't need to look up which encoding to use as ffmpeg should already know it. **Any suggestions?**

Comment: Along the same lines as Sadi, is there a way to "copy" the quality of the original video?

Comment: I would use the `-a:c copy` flag (goes after the `-vf` flag) to copy the audio stream. My phone's camera takes video using aac, which ffmpeg doesn't support by default on my distro.

Comment: For 180 you can use `-vf "transpose=2,transpose=2"`

Comment: @plutov.by Who transpose=2 and not transpose=1 twice?

Comment: @AlexReinking I think you meant `-c:a copy`.

Comment: Maybe I did... ffmpeg has some pretty fluid command-line flags. I posted that comment quite a while ago.

Comment: This worked for Windows 7 64 bit machine, ffmpeg-20141221-git-41ee459-win64-shared -- fyi, ffmpeg.exe wanted to take nearly 100% of the resources, so i adjusted the affinity on ffmpeg.exe in the processes tab of windows task manager to only use 2 cores instead of 8 (right-click the process)

Comment: @acron where we put it ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG `ffmpeg -i in.mov -qscale 0 -vf "transpose=1" out.mov` BUT read the man pages, as some codecs treat this differently. For example, when I recently worked with Theora, I had to use `-qscale 28` as it ignored `0` and wanted a 1 - 31 value.

Comment: Current docs note that "Numerical values are deprecated, and should be dropped in favor of symbolic constants." http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose Thus `cclock_flip`, `clock`, `cclock` or `clock_flip` instead of `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`.

Comment: Great Alexy, it worked for me too. I tested it in Windows 8.1

Comment: @Sadi [transcode using same codec and params as input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34442156/476716)

Comment: If you have an updated version of ffmpeg, it autorotates the video see http://superuser.com/questions/578321/how-to-rotate-a-video-180-with-ffmpeg

Comment: "transpose=2,transpose=2" - does this mean the rotation is done twice?? Meaning it will take double the time?

Comment: How can we achieve this in objective c code. We cant use "ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf "transpose=1" out.mov".

Comment: @KaluKhanLuhar Sure you can! You can use NSTask (or the Swift equivalent, Process). Note that this may not work in a sandboxed app.

Comment: The degrees are countwise, not anticountwise, like mathematicians do

Comment: Why my video size increase after transposing?

Comment: @Sisir, mine is decreases in quality. Yet to find a solution to this.

Comment: "Note that this will re-encode the audio and video parts" 

This disclaimer should have been at the beginning. No one wants to have their video quality suffer or wait an eternity and a half for their video to be encoded.

Comment: Here's the command I use that transposes the video without losing quality (by encoding to H265 losslessly) -- while this retains quality, it takes a long time to run:

`ffmpeg -i input.MP4 -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 -vf "transpose=2" rotated.mp4`

Comment: The fact that I was using Resolve for this and it was rendering so slow compared to FFMpeg that did it in 3X less time has me laughing right now.

Answer (score 251):

If you don't want to re-encode your video *and* your player can handle rotation metadata, you can just change the rotation in the metadata using FFmpeg with the flag `display_rotation` with the values `0`, `90`, `180` and `270`:

```
ffmpeg -display_rotation 90 -i input.mp4 -codec copy output.mp4
```

Older versions of FFmpeg that doesn't support the flag `display_rotation` can modify the metada using this flags:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map_metadata 0 -metadata:s:v rotate="90" -codec copy output.mp4
```

Comment: how about check the rotate metadata first with `ffmpeg -i input.m4v 2>&1  | grep rotate`

Comment: this worked for me. I want to upload Clash Royale to YouTube. It rotated the video 90 degrees without affecting quality.

Comment: This is the best answer by far. But there is a small improvement to do. To avoid loosing the remaining meta-data (such as date, camera) on the video do `ffmpeg -i input.m4v -map_metadata 0 -metadata:s:v rotate="90" -codec copy output.m4v`. This way all global metadata on the input file will be copied as global metadata to output file and only the rotation meta-data is changed.

Comment: If you have a portrait-mode video and just want to "UN-rotate" it to have a standard 1920x1080, then you probably want `rotate=0`.

Comment: Tried `-metadata:s:v rotate="180"`, didn't work. Is that supposed to work?

Comment: IMHO best solution because no reencoding is necessary and most video player support metadata rotation. Also Cloud services like Google Photos.
However, remember that ffmpeg does not necessarily copy all metadata from the original file!
Therefore, I would recommend to explicitly specify to copy all other metadata from original file:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -map_metadata 0 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 output.mp4`

Comment: Not a _proper_ solution since not all video players will honor the rotation. E.g. Snapchat (via the Camera Roll.)

Comment: As it was stated in the answer: "If you don't want to re-encode your video AND your player can handle rotation metadata"

Comment: This works great for Google Photos! However it should be noted ffmpeg won't copy all metadata and will leave out some metadata that might be useful (e.g. camera model). You can copy metadata after the fact using exiftool (https://video.stackexchange.com/a/28599/34178), e.g. `exiftool -TagsFromFile input.mov "-all:all>all:all" output.mov` (note that exiftool is smart enough not to overwrite the newly added rotation metadata)

Comment: Keep in mind that this method [is deprecated](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/b9058765d7422bb801af0e67fb58ba47e523f831)

Comment: @TheRandomGuyNamedJoe12 Do you have any command line example of the new way of changing the rotation metadata? It is about the "-display_rotation" flag?

Comment: @RodrigoPolo Yes it is about the "-display_rotation" flag and yes I have a command-line example but the question is closed.

Comment: @TheRandomGuyNamedJoe12 Indeed, I saw the flag and read the documentation, I even upgraded to the latest version, but it didn't work, you can put here the code with the command with no issue.

Comment: @RodrigoPolo Whether it works or not depends on the video format, MP4 works, WEBM does not and that applies to both my solution and the deprecated one

Comment: This answer is deprecated use "-display_rotation" instead Example command: `ffmpeg -display_rotation 90 -i input.m4v -codec copy output.m4v`

Comment: For some reason, 90 degrees rotation didn't work for me, but `-display_rotation 0` did!

Answer (score 103):

Use [`transpose`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose-1). Like (from the other answer):

```
 ffmpeg -i input -vf transpose=2 output
```

If you are using an old version, you have to update FFmpeg if you want to use the transpose feature, as it was added in October 2011.

The [FFmpeg download](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) page offers static builds that you can directly execute without having to compile them.

Comment: No, I have not. I didn't know it existed. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: The transpose filter does not seem to exist in any of my FFmpeg builds. How am I supposed to add it?

Comment: In the version of the docs as of 2011-05-15 the correct link is now http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC93

Comment: the answer from @Alexy seems more relevant

Comment: It feels like i got punished for offering a useful answer 1.5 years before the accepted answer.

Comment: How would this work with **more than 1 filter**? `-vf transpose=2 crop=20:20`? Because `-vf transpose=2 -vf crop=20:20` ignores the rotation (transpose). **Edit:**  `-vf transpose=2 crop=20:20` did not work.

Comment: @JonasB Separate the filters with commas. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195872/applying-multiple-filters-at-once-with-ffmpeg

Comment: @rwilliams While this is a great answer and was 1.5 years before Alexy's answer, it has the disadvantage that it doesn't include as much information on what transpose does or how to use it. It's great that you linked to it, but the disadvantage to linking to the pertinent info is that (as in this case) the link no longer points to the proper documentation. If nothing else I'll submit an edit to fix the link.

Comment: Be warned, this approach re-encodes the video and loses quality.

Answer (score 27):

To rotate the picture clockwise you can use the rotate filter, indicating a positive angle in radians. With 90 degrees equating with [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi)/2, you can do it like so:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "rotate=PI/2" out.mp4
```

For counterclockwise, the angle must be negative

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "rotate=-PI/2" out.mp4
```

The transpose filter will work equally well for 90 degrees, but for other angles this is a faster or the only choice.

Comment: this is great. I found that it's possible to get finer-grained resolution of radians, because `*` behaves as multiplication: `ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf "rotate=-8*PI/40" -q 1 out.avi`   (slightly less rotation than -PI/4 = -10*PI/40)

Answer (score 21):

I came across this page while searching for the same answer.  It is now six months since this was originally asked and the builds have been updated many times since then.  However, I wanted to add an answer for anyone else that comes across here looking for this information.

I am using [Debian 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_6.0_(Squeeze)) (Squeeze) and **FFmpeg** version from those repositories.

The [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) for FFmpeg states the following use:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mpg -vf "transpose=1" outputfile.mpg
```

The key being that you are not to use a degree variable, but a predefined setting variable from the man page.

```
0=90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip  (default)
1=90Clockwise
2=90CounterClockwise
3=90Clockwise and Vertical Flip
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was never able to actually get this working, as I generally have trouble building from source. I may see if I can get it working again now.

Comment: transpose=3 is causing the image to mirror

Comment: transpose=2 worked without mirroring for my 270 rotated video

Answer (score 12):

```
ffmpeg -vfilters "rotate=90" -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

won't work, even with the latest source...

You must change the order:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf vflip output.mp4
```

It works fine.

Comment: that is becuase you're applying the filter to the wrong file... try ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "rotate=90" output.mp4, then it'll work

Comment: "Rotate video by an arbitrary angle expressed in __radians__." Documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate So, radians `rotate=PI/2` or `rotate=90*PI/180` is needed

Answer (score 8):

If you're getting a "Codec is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled" error use this :

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile -vf "transpose=1" -c:a copy outputFile
```

Happened with me for some .mov file with aac audio.

Comment: This was the only example that worked for me, but the quality was terrible, and very blocky.  Also, it downsized a 1080x1920 video to 352x640. I guess I'm missing a switch or two.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @LOlliffe add `-sameq`

Comment: @AndrewSchleifer Thanks.  I tried that, but ffmpeg threw back at me `Option 'sameq' was removed. If you are looking for an option to preserve the quality (which is not what -sameq was for), use -qscale 0 or an equivalent quality factor option.
Failed to set value '1' for option 'sameq': Invalid argument`  -qscale also gives an error. `Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous`, but still works.

Answer (score 8):

An additional solution with a different approach from the last mentioned solutions, is to check if your camera driver supports the v4l2 camera controls (which is very common). 
In the terminal, just type:

```
v4l2-ctl -L
```

If your camera driver supports the v4l2 camera controls, you should get something like this (the list below depends on the controls that your camera driver supports):

```
               contrast (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=slider
             saturation (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=64 value=64 flags=slider
                    hue (int)    : min=0 max=359 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=slider
white_balance_automatic (bool)   : default=1 value=1 flags=update
            red_balance (int)    : min=0 max=4095 step=1 default=0 value=128 flags=inactive, slider
           blue_balance (int)    : min=0 max=4095 step=1 default=0 value=128 flags=inactive, slider
               exposure (int)    : min=0 max=65535 step=1 default=0 value=885 flags=inactive, volatile
         gain_automatic (bool)   : default=1 value=1 flags=update
                   gain (int)    : min=0 max=1023 step=1 default=0 value=32 flags=inactive, volatile
        horizontal_flip (bool)   : default=0 value=0
          vertical_flip (bool)   : default=0 value=0
```

And if you are lucky it supports **horizontal_flip** and **vertical_flip**. 
Then all you need to do is to set the **horizontal_flip** by:

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl horizontal_flip=1
```

Or the **vertical_flip** by:

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl vertical_flip=1
```

And then you can call your video device to capture a new video (see example below), and the video will be rotated/flipped.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -f mpegts input.mp4
```

Of course that if you need to process an already existing video, then this method is not the solution you are looking for.

The advantage in this approach is that we flip the image in the sensor level, so the sensor of the driver already gives us the image flipped, and that's saves the application (like FFmpeg) any further and unnecessary processing.

Comment: Great information about v4l2 here. Rotating to the correct orientation at recording time is obviously preferable :) This almost 10 year old question (wow!) was originally asked about videos being uploaded from iOS devices if that helps provide any context :)

Comment: I'm a bit new in this community and this question is much older then my seniority here... I truly think it's a good (and common) question, so I believe this old question will keep helping many FFmpeg users.

Answer (score 3):

This script that will output the files with the directory structure under "fixedFiles". At the moment it is fixed to MOV files and will execute a number of transformations depending on the original "rotation" of the video. It works with iOS captured videos on a Mac running [Mac OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (Mavericks), but it should be easily exportable. It relies on having installed both [ExifTool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) and [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Rotation of 90 degrees. It will have to concatenate.
#ffmpeg -i <originalfile> -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -vf "transpose=1" <destinationfile>
#/VLC -I dummy -vvv <originalfile> --sout='#transcode{width=1280,vcodec=mp4v,vb=16384,vfilter={canvas{width=1280,height=1280}:rotate{angle=-90}}}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=<outputfile>}\' vlc://quit

# Allowing blanks in file names
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

# Bit Rate
BR=16384

# Where to store fixed files
FIXED_FILES_DIR="fixedFiles"
#rm -rf $FIXED_FILES_DIR
mkdir $FIXED_FILES_DIR

# VLC media player
VLC_START="/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I dummy -vvv"
VLC_END="vlc://quit"


#############################################
# Processing of MOV in the wrong orientation
for f in `find . -regex '\./.*\.MOV'`
do
  ROTATION=`exiftool "$f" |grep Rotation|cut -c 35-38`
  SHORT_DIMENSION=`exiftool "$f" |grep "Image Size"|cut -c 39-43|sed 's/x//'`
  BITRATE_INT=`exiftool "$f" |grep "Avg Bitrate"|cut -c 35-38|sed 's/\..*//'`
  echo Short dimension [$SHORT_DIMENSION] $BITRATE_INT

  if test "$ROTATION" != ""; then
    DEST=$(dirname ${f})
    echo "Processing $f with rotation $ROTATION in directory $DEST"
    mkdir -p $FIXED_FILES_DIR/"$DEST"

    if test "$ROTATION" == "0"; then
      cp "$f" "$FIXED_FILES_DIR/$f"

    elif test "$ROTATION" == "180"; then
#      $(eval $VLC_START \"$f\" "--sout="\'"#transcode{vfilter={rotate{angle=-"$ROTATION"}},vcodec=mp4v,vb=$BR}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=\""$FIXED_FILES_DIR/$f"\"}'" $VLC_END )
      $(eval ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -vf hflip,vflip -r 30 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -b:v "$BITRATE_INT"M -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy \"$FIXED_FILES_DIR/$f\")

    elif test "$ROTATION" == "270"; then
      $(eval ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -vf "scale=$SHORT_DIMENSION:-1,transpose=2,pad=$SHORT_DIMENSION:$SHORT_DIMENSION:\(ow-iw\)/2:0" -r 30 -s "$SHORT_DIMENSION"x"$SHORT_DIMENSION" -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -b:v "$BITRATE_INT"M -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy \"$FIXED_FILES_DIR/$f\" )

    else
#      $(eval $VLC_START \"$f\" "--sout="\'"#transcode{scale=1,width=$SHORT_DIMENSION,vcodec=mp4v,vb=$BR,vfilter={canvas{width=$SHORT_DIMENSION,height=$SHORT_DIMENSION}:rotate{angle=-"$ROTATION"}}}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=\""$FIXED_FILES_DIR/$f"\"}'" $VLC_END )
      echo ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -vf "scale=$SHORT_DIMENSION:-1,transpose=1,pad=$SHORT_DIMENSION:$SHORT_DIMENSION:\(ow-iw\)/2:0" -r 30 -s "$SHORT_DIMENSION"x"$SHORT_DIMENSION" -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -b:v "$BITRATE_INT"M -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy \"$FIXED_FILES_DIR/$f\"
      $(eval ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -vf "scale=$SHORT_DIMENSION:-1,transpose=1,pad=$SHORT_DIMENSION:$SHORT_DIMENSION:\(ow-iw\)/2:0" -r 30 -s "$SHORT_DIMENSION"x"$SHORT_DIMENSION" -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 -b:v "$BITRATE_INT"M -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy \"$FIXED_FILES_DIR/$f\" )

    fi

  fi

echo
echo ==================================================================
sleep 1
done

#############################################
# Processing of AVI files for my Panasonic TV
# Use ffmpegX + QuickBatch. Bitrate at 16384. Camera res 640x424
for f in `find . -regex '\./.*\.AVI'`
do
  DEST=$(dirname ${f})
  DEST_FILE=`echo "$f" | sed 's/.AVI/.MOV/'`
  mkdir -p $FIXED_FILES_DIR/"$DEST"
  echo "Processing $f in directory $DEST"
  $(eval ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -r 20 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 8M -flags +aic+mv4 \"$FIXED_FILES_DIR/$DEST_FILE\" )
echo
echo ==================================================================

done

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: Ouch... This may work, but it is perfectly hideous. First of all, the general rule of shell-programming: you never need more than one of grep, cut, awk, or sed in a pipe. Any grep|cut|sed is doable with either sed or awk alone. Then, more specifically, exiftool can be asked to output just the tag(s) you want -- so instead of filtering out the Rotation, just "exiftool -Rotation".
Third, you don't need so many "evals" and your "if test..." should be replaced with case $ROTATION in -- for both readability and efficiency. Good luck!

Comment: No dice: `[Parsed_pad_2 @ 0x7f8b15c3a580] Input area -420:0:1500:1080 not within the padded area 0:0:1080:1080 or zero-sized`\n `
`[Parsed_pad_2 @ 0x7f8b15c3a580] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_2`\n 
`Error reinitializing filters!`\n
`Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument`\n
`Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0`\n
`Conversion failed!`

Answer (score 3):

Since the FFmpeg transpose command is very slow, use the command below to rotate a video by 90 degrees clockwise.

Fast command (without encoding):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=270 output.mp4
```

For full video encoding (slow command, does encoding):

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile -vf "transpose=1" -c:a copy
```

Comment: Note that the fast command is only adding video metadata, which may already be present in many sources. The issue will be whether or not the player rendering the video respects the metadata flag or not :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as the OP, getting the `No such filter: 'rotate'` error, even though the rotate filter shows as supported in `--filters`.

I needed to rotate by **an arbitrary angle**, and so all the current answers which are alternatives to rotating by a multiple of 90 degrees didn't work. I figured out that the syntax for `-vf` *requires spaces around the tokens*, which is contrary to the [official documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-100).

Changing:

`-vf 'rotate=1.23'`

to

`-vf 'rotate = 1.23'`

got it to work for me.

Full example:

`ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -vf "rotate = 3.0 , crop = 1920:1080" out.mp4`

For what it's worth, this is on FFmpeg version 4.3.2.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the *ffmpeg.exe* rotate filter may cut images. In order to keep the original window width and height, to rotate 90° counterclockwise, one can use this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i infilename -vf rotate=-PI/2:oh=iw:ow=ih outfilename
```

By adding `:oh=iw:ow=ih`, it specifies that [out window width] = [input window height], [out window width] = [input window height]. This is equivalent to -vf transpose=2, rotating without image cutting.

Here:

```
iw: input width
ih: input height
ow: output width
oh: output height
```

Please see *[11.210 rotate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate)*.

Comment: `PI/2` repeatedly manages a 180' clockwise rotation for me. I'm using the same player for input and output so not sure what could be going on ...

Answer (score 2):

[Alexy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg/9570992#9570992) almost worked for me except that I was getting this error:

> timebase 1/90000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum
> admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535

I just had to add a parameter (-r 65535/2733) to the command and it worked. The full command was thus:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" -r 65535/2733 out.mp4
```

Comment: If you're looking for a "NTSC-film" framerate, then `24000/1001` would be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Smartphone: Recorded a video in vertical format

We want to send it to a website it was 90° to the left (counterclockwise, landscape format). Hmm.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "rotate=0" output.mp4`

does it. I got the vertical format back again.

[Debian 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_10_(Buster)) (Buster): `ffmpeg --version`

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) version of FFmpeg does support video filters.

You need to use avidemux or some other editor to achieve the same effect.

In the programmatic way, mencoder has been recommended.

Comment: Did you mean "Ubuntu version of ffmpeg does *not* support videofilters"?

Comment: FYI: "FFmpeg has returned in Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet." or can be compiled for Ubuntu. --> http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: avconv does (in 14.04), and seems to work exactly the same. (But for later versions, definitely use FFmpeg.)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What version of FFmpeg? In 2011, it could have been the LTS [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx).

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 11 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?

Answer (score 1):

For me it works like this:

Rotate clockwise

```
 ffmpeg -i "path_source_video.mp4" -filter:v "transpose=1" "path_output_video.mp4"
```

Rotate counterclockwise

```
 ffmpeg -i "path_source_video.mp4" -filter:v "transpose=0,transpose=1,transpose=0" -acodec copy "path_output_video.mp4"
```

The package I use is [zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at ffmpeg.zeranoe.com."*