# Applying multiple filters at once with FFMPEG

Tags: filter, ffmpeg

I have the need to apply fadein and overlay filters to a video. Is it possible to apply 2 filters at once?

I got:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vf "movie=watermark.png [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10 [out]" output.mpg
```

I'm trying to add `fade=in:0:20`, but if I add a new `-vf` parameter, it will overwrite the preceding one, and if I add:

```
-vf "fade=in:0:20; movie=......"
```

it won't work.

Is this possible or do I have to run FFmpeg twice?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Okay, someone helped me somewhere.

I had to separate filters with commas:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vf "movie=watermark.png [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10, fade=in:0:20 [out]" output.mpg
```

This will apply fadein to both the watermark and the video.

Comment: I am currently trying this with `mencoder -vf "rotate=180,flip" -o out.avi -oac mp3lame -ovc lavc in.mp4` but it doesn't work. Any hints?

Comment: What does `[out]` means is a it a placeholder or is it required ?

Answer (score 28):

Yes it is possible .

```
ffmpeg.exe -i yourvideo.avi -vf "[in] scale=iw/2:ih/2, pad=iw+40:ih+40:10:10 [top]; movie=yourLogoOrVideo.pngOraviEtc, scale=iw/2:ih/2 , fade=out:400:40:alpha=1 [bottom]; [top][bottom] overlay=PaddingFromTop:PaddingFromLeft [out]" -f flv ff.flv
```

Comment: what does the the real filter graph look like? does ffmpeg actualy to it in this order? if you were going to crop, unsharp, denoise, etc

Comment: I've found out that yes, ffmpeg applies the filters in the order specified; thus it's not a good idea to e.g. hardsub subtitles first and then apply sharpening filter, e.g. like this: 
`-vf "scale=1920:1080 , subtitles=subtitles.ass , unsharp=3.0:3.0:1.5"`
(that's how I found it out accidentally)