# Applying two filters at once with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, crop

i use this command for padding my video:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf "pad=width=254:height=254:x=0:y=50:color=#ffff55" 2.mp4
```

and this command for adding watermark to the video:

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=arial.ttf: text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=#ffff55: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy 3.mp4
```

i want to combine these two command in one command. i see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195872) and try several times without success...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain the filters together,

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf "pad=254:254:0:50:color=#ffff55,drawtext=fontfile=arial.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=#ffff55:ontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -c:a copy 3.mp4
```