# With ffmpeg, how to double a stream while applying a filter to the second copy?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using Plex, which always considers the first audio stream, but is also failing to decode surround media files on my stereo system (my laptop).

For that reason, I intend to downmix (following a formula suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1410620/1112751), which is an improvement over `-ac 2`) a bunch of files so I have:

```
Stream 0:0 > Video
Stream 0:1 > 2.0 Filtered audio
Stream 0:2 > 5.1 Original audio
```

The problem is that while my downmixing requires filtering, the doubling of a stream requires copying and I found out that these 2 doesn't seem to go together, although it seems to me this could be done because while the filtering and copying are applied for the same *input* stream, they're not for the same *output* stream.

Here's my currently failing command:

```
ffmpeg -i "INPUT.mkv" -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 ac3 -vol 425 -filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=stereo|FL=0.5*FC+0.707*FL+0.707*BL+0.5*LFE|FR=0.5*FC+0.707*FR+0.707*BR+0.5*LFE" -map 0:a:0 -c:a:0 copy  "OUTPUT.mkv"
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to map 5.1 audio to 2 output audio streams: filtered 2.0 and original 5.1. You are on a right track but mixed up in the stream specifiers. Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i "INPUT.mkv" \
  -filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=stereo|FL=0.5*FC+0.707*FL+0.707*BL+0.5*LFE|FR=0.5*FC+0.707*FR+0.707*BR+0.5*LFE,volume=1.66[filtered]" \
  -map 0:v -c:v copy \
  -map [filtered] -c:a:0 ac3 \
  -map 0:a:0 -c:a:1 copy \
  "OUTPUT.mkv"
```

Changes: (1) named filter output as `[filtered]`, (2) 2nd output audio stream should be `a:1`, (3) moved volume setting to `complex_filter`

Edit Note: Reflects Fabio and Lex's comments to the answer

Comment: This almost works, but volume should be adjusted only for the 2.0 stream. It also seems `-vol` has been deprecated and must be passed as an audio filter, I believe the proper way to do so is `"[0:a:0]volume=1.66,pan=stereo|FL=0.5*FC+0.707*FL+0.707*BL+0.5*LFE|FR=0.5*FC+0.707*FR+0.707*BR+0.5*LFE[filtered]"`?

Comment: @FabioFreitas You can replace `[filtered]` in @kesh's complex filter with `[a];[a]volume=1.66[filtered]`.

Comment: `-filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=stereo|FL=0.5*FC+0.707*FL+0.707*BL+0.5*LFE|FR=0.5*FC+0.707*FR+0.707*BR+0.5*LFE[a];[a]volume=1.66[filtered]"`

Comment: It seems both versions produce the exact same file, byte for byte. I inferred my version from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12402374/12194725), good to know that.

Comment: @Lex - I like moving the volume filter to the end as it saves the computation a bit (2 channels vs. 6 channels) but no need to make a graph when you are butting a single-output filter with a single-input filter.

Comment: I think you can replace that multiple codecs with just two:  `-map 0:v -map [filtered] -map 0:a:0 -c copy -c:a:0 ac3` - that should copy all the streams except the first audio. Am I right?

Comment: @Lex - That sounds right, but I've never verified it myself.