# ffmpeg auto dection portrait then do the necessary flip

Tags: iphone, rotation, ffmpeg

Is it possible to have ffmpeg detect the video size, and if it's not landscape, have it do the rotate to 90 degress clockwise? I have found an article here, but am not sure if it can detect this automatically or not: [Rotating videos with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 1):

If your decision is based on height and width a very simple script around ffmpeg can do this for you

ffprobe yourfile

In the output you will have height and width parameters available for the stream. Run a regex on it.

Based on height and width take decision in your script to rotate or not

Call ffmpeg with the right parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
-autorotate
```

> Automatically rotate the video according to file metadata. Enabled by default, use `-noautorotate` to disable it.