# ffmpeg output Filename from multiple source

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I want to have the output file to have same name from source ( for eg first filename from `list.txt`), how can I do it?

This is the code I have which converts the all the .avi in folder to a single files and renames it to `output.avi`.

Instead of `output.avi` I want the filename to be same as first filename from source folder or first filename from `list.txt`.

```
for %%f in (*.avi) do (
    echo file %%f >> list.txt
)
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.avi
del list.txt
```

One more thing I want to know, is it possible to flip video horizontal or mirror it without re-encoding?

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. Multi question posts tend to get ignored or get partial answers which often don't get accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ffmpeg supports "backreferencing" the input filenames. I suggest handling that in bash or some through other means of scripting. E.g. you can use the first line of `list.txt` as the output filename like this (untested):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output/$(head -1 list.txt)
```

In this example if the first line is `foo.avi`, the output will be saved at `output/foo.avi`.

> is it possible to flip video horizontal or mirror it without re-encoding

Apparently you can [set rotation metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27768317/3688648) without re-encoding to hint video players to play it back with the given rotation. Maybe there are metadata flags for mirroring or flipping, but I couldn't find any.

If this does not work for you, I don't believe there is a built-in solution to do this without re-encoding.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to flip video horizontal or mirror it without re-encoding?

No, not when using filters (such as hflip, vflip, rotate, etc). Filtering requires re-encoding.

Rotation metadata as mentioned in another answer may suffice this use case, but support among players is not universal. There is no metadata for mirroring or flipping: only rotation.

If that is not acceptable then the player itself may have mirroring/flipping capabilities. Example:

```
mpv -vf hflip video.mp4
```