# How to rotate a portrait GoPro video?

Tags: video, rotation, gopro

I took some landscape videos with a GoPro and, for some reason, they're played as a portrait ones. It seems that the camera understood that it was handled in portrait and automatically did something. I want to rotate them to landscape.

I tried with some StackOverflow accepted answers like [Rotate mp4 videos without re-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031557/rotate-mp4-videos-without-re-encoding) or this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ViktorNova/1dd68a2ec99781fd9adca49507c73ee2) but they give an invalid rotation or do nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Mac using `brew`, install `ffmpeg` running `brew install ffmpeg` and then run this for every video:

`ffmpeg -i input.MP4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 output.MP4`

By the way, it also works for upside-down videos.