# Rotate frames and create a viedo with ffmpeg, without re encoding

Tags: python, image, video, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I am using the following to copy a couple of frames to a video, and I am trying to rotate the frames before copying them to a video, but I am not sure if its possible with ffmpeg. I dont want to create the video and rotate because I'll have to re encode it and it takes a lot of time.

ffmpeg -framerate 6 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c copy out.mp4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take a look at: [Rotate mp4 videos without re-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031557/rotate-mp4-videos-without-re-encoding).