# Set rotation metadata with gstreamer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer, video-processing

I recording and muxing video with gstreamer. How to set rotation to 90?

I seen [Can I set rotation field for a video stream with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335073/can-i-set-rotation-field-for-a-video-stream-with-ffmpeg/15336581#15336581)

I tried taginject - unknown tag 'rotation'

Using h264 with mkv container for now. Writing `python` code with `Gst` from `gi.repository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I save video to file, then tag it with [MP4Box](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/MP4Box), and finally load it back into GStreamer.

```
MP4Box -mx 1=0:-65536:0:65536:0:0:0:0:1073741824 '/path/video.mp4'
```