# using FFmpeg converter from .mov format from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, html5-video, converters

I have a critical problem. I am sharing the details with you.

Problem: - I have a video file in .mov format, taken from the IPhone. This video is in portrait mode, I want to play this video on the webpage in landscape mode and vice versa.

Please suggest me, should I convert my video from portrait to landscape mode using FFMPEG. Does FFMPEG provide this conversion feature? If yes, Please send the exe and the command line for converting portrait video into landscape mode and vice versa.
i am using these commands

```
ffmpeg -i "Inputname.mov" -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b 345k output.webm
ffmpeg -i "Inputname.mov" -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 output.mp4

ffmpeg -i "Inputname.mov" -b 1500k -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -g 30 output.ogv
```

any one can help to solve this issue

Comment: Are you looking to rotate the video? Crop it? add letterbox/pillarbox?

Comment: I want to rotate when it is in portrait mode, Because it is showing me in landscap when i use it in <video> tag of html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to Fix this issue my self 
I install  mediainfo on my linux centos

```
     yum install mediainfo

     $ffmpeg = "/usr/path/of/ffmpeg";
     $pathinfo = pathinfo($video->video_path.$video->video_name);
  $video_path = $video->video_path.$video->video_name;
  // get rotation of the video
   if($pathinfo['extension']=='mov'){

      $result = shell_exec("mediainfo ".getcwd()."/".$video->video_path.$video->video_name." | grep Rotation");
       //$rotate  = explode(":", $result);
     preg_match("|\d+|", $result,$rotation);

     if ($rotation[0]  == "90")
     {
       shell_exec($ffmpeg . ' -i ' . $video_path . '  -vf "transpose=1" -sameq ' . $video_path . ".rot.mov ") . "\n";
          shell_exec("mv $video_path.rot.mov $video_path") . "\n";
        }
        else if ($rotation[0] == "180")
        {
          shell_exec($ffmpeg . ' -i ' . $video_path . '  -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" -sameq ' . $video_path . ".rot2.mov ") . "\n";
        //echo shell_exec($ffmpeg . ' -i ' . $video_path . '.rot2.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" ' . $video_path . ".rot.mp4  ") . "\n";
          shell_exec("mv $video_path.rot2.mov $video_path") . "\n";
        }
        else if ($rotation[0] == "270")
        {
          shell_exec($ffmpeg . ' -i ' . $video_path . '  -vf "transpose=2" -sameq ' . $video_path . ".rot.mov ") . "\n";
          shell_exec("mv $video_path.rot.mov $video_path") . "\n";
        }
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are simply trying to scale it you can use:

```
-vf scale='width':-1
```

Simple replace width with the desired width. The `:-1` will keep the original aspect ratio rather than stretching the video.

However, if what you want is to rotate the video, you should see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570992/2345443

Comment: I just want to rotate when it is in portrait mode