# rotate video in iOS with fully compatible with any player

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want to rotate video file . for that I find a way

1. using  `AVMutableVidoeCompositionLayerInstruction`  method `setTransform: AtTime:`

   - Will this approach rotate the every frame of video or simply set the transform matrix property in video header file ?

if this add transform matrix to header instead of rotating avery frame of video then I am afraid for portability in others players.

what is the best way to rotate an video with portability ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "portability"?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ffmpeg` library to rotate the video which will support portability.

You just go through following links then you will get some idea

[ffmpeg.org](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

[Rotating videos with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg)