# How to watermark text on video sliding from right top to right bottom vertically

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

How to watermark text on video sliding from right top to right bottom vertically?

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i /usr/home/test.mp4 -vf "drawbox=x=iw-42:y=0:w=42:h=ih:color=black@0.5:t=80,drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerifBold.ttf:text='Hello World':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=16: y=(mod(2*n\,h+th)-th):x=w-tw-10" -codec:v libx264 -codec:a copy -strict -2 /usr/home/out.mp4
```

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the optimum method to do this. Still you can rotate video 90 degree counterclockwise, apply the text and rotate video 90 degree clockwise. These steps will result you the vertical text on the video.

- **Rotate video**

You can use [`transpose`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose) or [`rotate`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate) to rotate the video clockwise and anticlockwise. [`Rotating videos with ffmpeg`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg) question has a good set of explanations regarding this.

- **Draw text**

To add text to a video you can use [`drawtext`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter. Document it self has a good explanation and set of [examples](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-35) which you can followup.

By using these two functions you can apply the text vertically. Following command will work for you.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -filter_complex "
[0:v]transpose=2[anticlockwiserotated];
[anticlockwiserotated]drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf: text='Test Text':x=100: y=50: fontsize=36: fontcolor=white:[textapplied];
[textapplied]transpose=1" output_video
```

Here you need to use `filter_complex` which will apply the required filters and chain them accordingly. `[0:v]` refers to the first input source which is the video. Instead of `font.ttf` you have to use the absolute path to the font source.

Hope this helps!