# Remove Unwanted Rotation of video when merge audio With Video Using FFMPEG

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-processing

Actually I want to overwrite Audio Using  Recorder Audio file into Recorded Video File.For That I am Using **FFMPEG** Library Project from [this Link](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java)

**Issue:**
When I capture video in **Portrait mode** and then merge video with recorded audio merging is working fine but the problem is Video is rotate 90 Degree and then merging is work.I don't Want to rotate video I want to do merge Only.

if I capture video in Landscape Mode Then Merging audio is Working Fine.

Below Currently FFMPEG Command is Used for merging Audio with Video File

```
ffmpeg -y -i Video.mp4 -i Audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 OutputFile.mp4
```

And I Have Tried Using Below Commands also but it's Not working

```
ffmpeg -y -i Video.mp4 -i Audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  -vf -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 OutputFile.mp4
```

And

```
ffmpeg -y -i Video.mp4 -i Audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  -vf -metadata:s:v:0 translate=1 OutputFile.mp4
```

And I have Trying othe possibility also but its not work for me.

Any Help Would be Acceptable.

Thanks In Advance

Log cat is displaying below

```
WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.informer.favoraid/app_bin/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 
built on Feb  7 2015 21:39:25 with gcc 4.6 20120106 (prerelease)
configuration: --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/home/josh/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/home/josh/android-ndk/platforms/android-16/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fPIE -pie' --extra-ldflags='-L../x264 -fPIE -pie' --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filters --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-outdevs --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --enable-muxer=md5
libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.informer.favoraid/files/MP4_FAV20151002_105039_1099425693.mp4':



10-01 17:15:20.056: I/System.out(6526): sxCon> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 
    '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.informer.favoraid/files/MP4_FAV20151001_171355_-1450037636.mp4':

  Metadata:
     major_brand     : mp42
     minor_version   : 0
     compatible_brands: isommp42
     creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
   Duration: 00:00:04.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15488 kb/s
     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 16004 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
     Metadata:
       rotate          : 90
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
       handler_name    : VideoHandle
     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
 Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.informer.favoraid/Audio_Recording.mp4':
   Metadata:
     major_brand     : mp42
     minor_version   : 0
     compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:45:13
  Duration: 00:00:05.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18 kb/s
     Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 12 kb/s
     Metadata:
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:45:13
       handler_name    : SoundHandle
 Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.informer.favoraid/OutputFile.mp4':
   Metadata:
   :     major_brand     : mp42
     minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
     encoder         : Lavf54.6.100
     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (![0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 16004 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
     Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
     creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (@[0][0][0] / 0x0040), 8000 Hz, mono, 12 kb/s
     Metadata:
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:45:13
       handler_name    : SoundHandle
 Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
   Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 frame=  138 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    9008kB time=00:00:04.57 bitrate=16141.8kbits/s
```

Comment: You need to show the **complete** `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have paste complete ffmpeg console here...which kind of information you want?

Comment: Actually I want to disable  `Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 16004 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
     Metadata:
       rotate          : 90
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
       handler_name    : VideoHandle
     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:` this command

Comment: [Crossposting the same question](http://superuser.com/questions/981068/remove-unwanted-rotation-of-video-when-merge-audio-with-video-using-ffmpeg) to multiple Stack Exchange is discouraged (and it is offtopic here anyway).

Comment: i have addeed ffmpeg version and configuraion

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer.while capturing video using both front and rear camera, you find the angle and based on angle you execute the ffmpeg command ...  Refer with this link you will get some idea 
[Rotating videos with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg)

http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Comment: I have already tryed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg And http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html This link is help full for me and I can rotate but not satisfied with output quality and i can not enter fixed bitrate......Thanks......

Comment: do You have Idea about -pix_fmt YUV420P?