# How can I pass a rotation angle to the ffmpeg library?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

For crop the video in Android, the only solution I founded: ffmpeg library. After reading documentation I do not quite understand what parameters the command line receives.
For example,

> String[] cmd = {"-i", in, "-filter:v", "crop=" + 240 + ":" + 120 + ":" + 100 + ":" + 100, "-c:a", "copy", out};

How can apply the Rotation Angle?

What is the correct **cmd** for video cropping?

Comment: Please, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138683/how-to-crop-video-with-ffmpeg-library-in-android/41298781#41298781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quick googling found following.

[Cropping video](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/4571) (Nicely explained answer)

Video rotation ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf "transpose=1" out.mov
```

valid options for transpose

```
0 = 90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default)
1 = 90Clockwise
2 = 90CounterClockwise
3 = 90Clockwise and Vertical Flip
```

I hope this helps

video rotation answer [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570992/2930834)