# How to crop video with ffmpeg library in Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, camera, android-camera, android-ffmpeg

To crop video in Android app I use [ffmpeg](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) library

In SO [example](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg/4571#4571) I found for cropping the video the following command:

> ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4

I created a String array:

> String[] cmd = {"ffmpeg", "-i", originalVideoPath, "-vf", "\"crop=" + imageWidth + ":" + imageHeight + ":" + xCoordinate + ":" + yCoordinate + "\"", "-c:a", "copy", croppedVideoPath};

And I pass this array to execute() method:

```
    try {
            ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getContext());
            ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onStart: Crop Video started");
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(String message) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onProgress: " + message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: " + message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: " + message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onFinish: Video cropping finished");
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: Exception + Device is not supported");
        }
```

The log result is:

```
 12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/com.studioidan.dmc I/CropImageFragment: onStart: Crop Video started
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
12-14 11:33:33.246 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DMC/diamondVideo.mp4':
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   Metadata:
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     major_brand     : isom
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     minor_version   : 0
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     compatible_brands: isom3gp4
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:33:10
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:05.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13480 kb/s
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 13824 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.96 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     Metadata:
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:       creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:33:10
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:       handler_name    : VideoHandle
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     Metadata:
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:       creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:33:10
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress: [NULL @ 0x433f5f40] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
12-14 11:33:33.316 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress: ffmpeg: Invalid argument
12-14 11:33:33.326 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onFailure: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DMC/diamondVideo.mp4':
                                                                   Metadata:
                                                                     major_brand     : isom
                                                                     minor_version   : 0
                                                                     compatible_brands: isom3gp4
                                                                     creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:33:10
                                                                   Duration: 00:00:05.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13480 kb/s
                                                                     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 13824 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.96 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                                     Metadata:
                                                                       creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:33:10
                                                                       handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                                     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
                                                                     Metadata:
                                                                       creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:33:10
                                                                       handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                                 [NULL @ 0x433f5f40] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
                                                                 ffmpeg: Invalid argument
 12-14 11:33:33.326 5731-5731/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onFinish: Video cropping finished
```

But when I delete ffmpeg from array of command

> String[] cmd = {"-i", originalVideoPath, "-vf", "\"crop=" + imageWidth + ":" + imageHeight + ":" + xCoordinate + ":" + yCoordinate + "\"", "-c:a", "copy", croppedVideoPath};

After execute it, the result is:

```
 12-14 11:56:46.366 25930-26592/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onStart: Crop Video started
 12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers

 12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)

 12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
 12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
 12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  12-14 11:56:46.426 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DMC/diamondVideo.mp4':
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   Metadata:
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     major_brand     : isom
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     minor_version   : 0
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     compatible_brands: isom3gp4
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:56:40
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:05.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13189 kb/s
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 13886 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30.01 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     Metadata:
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:       creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:56:40
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:       handler_name    : VideoHandle
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:     Metadata:
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:       creation_time   : 2016-12-14 08:56:40
  12-14 11:56:46.506 25930-25930/dmc I/CropImageFragment: onProgress:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

It looks like the process starts and after that it freezes

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own implementation:

```
private void cropVideo(String originalVideoPath, String croppedVideoPath, int xCoordinate,
                       int yCoordinate, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int croppedAngle) {
    String command;
    ffmpegCommand = new StringBuilder();
    ffmpegCommand.append("-y");
    ffmpegCommand.append(" ");
    ffmpegCommand.append("-i");
    ffmpegCommand.append(" ");
    ffmpegCommand = getFFmpegCommand(ffmpegCommand, imageWidth, imageHeight,
            xCoordinate, yCoordinate, originalVideoPath, croppedVideoPath, croppedAngle);
    command = ffmpegCommand.toString();

    Log.i(TAG, command);
    String[] cmd = command.split(" ");

    new CropVideoTask().execute(cmd);

}

private StringBuilder getFFmpegCommand(StringBuilder ffmpegCommand, int imageWidth,
                                           int imageHeight, int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate,
                                           String originalVideoPath, String croppedVideoPath, int angle) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int w = 0;
        int h = 0;
        String rotate = "";
        switch (angle) {
            case 0:
                x = xCoordinate;
                y = yCoordinate;
                w = imageWidth;
                h = imageHeight;
                break;
            case 90:
                x = yCoordinate;
                y = mFileWidth - imageWidth - xCoordinate;
                w = imageHeight;
                h = imageWidth;
                rotate = ",transpose=1";
                break;
            case 180:
                x = mFileHeight - imageWidth - xCoordinate;
                y = mFileWidth - imageHeight - yCoordinate;
                w = imageWidth;
                h = imageHeight;
                rotate = ",vflip";
                break;
            case -90:
                x = mFileHeight - imageHeight - yCoordinate;
                y = xCoordinate;
                w = imageHeight;
                h = imageWidth;
                rotate = ",transpose=2";
                break;
        }

        ffmpegCommand.append(originalVideoPath);
        ffmpegCommand.append(" ");
        ffmpegCommand.append("-vf");
        ffmpegCommand.append(" ");
        ffmpegCommand.append("crop=");
        ffmpegCommand.append(w);
        ffmpegCommand.append(":");
        ffmpegCommand.append(h);
        ffmpegCommand.append(":");
        ffmpegCommand.append(x);
        ffmpegCommand.append(":");
        ffmpegCommand.append(y);
        ffmpegCommand.append(rotate);
        ffmpegCommand.append(" ");
        ffmpegCommand.append(croppedVideoPath);

        return ffmpegCommand;
    }

private class CropVideoTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(String[]... cmd) {
            try {
                ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getContext());
                ffmpeg.execute(cmd[0], new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String message) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String message) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String message) {
                      // Do something with the cropped video                   
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                });
            } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground: Exception + Device is not supported");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share me the complete class for this implementation

Comment: @RahulGoswami  my project stuck beacuse of it.. please share codes with me.. Thanks