# FFMPEG out image rotating 180 degrees automatically

Tags: ffmpeg, autorotate, android-ffmpeg

I am using below command for image compression using FFMPEG. After executing command file rotating by 180 degrees in 6 inch above devices.

```
"-y -i "+srcfile + " -vf scale=320:-1 " + targetpath + File.separator + filename
```

Comment: Add `-noautorotate` as mentioned in the duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

See:
[Rotating videos with FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg)

Not a great question, there's no actual command line we could use to reproduce the problem.
If you've seen this on multiple input video types/files, that's important to note.

Nothing you've shown here should rotate the video. Some cameras (phones?) include an orientation sensor value that tell that device to rotate the video when displaying it, but the video may actually be encoded in something other than what you expect.

See:  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose-1