# Mix multiple audios into one with FFmpeg

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg

I have a lot of audio files I want to mix down into one audio file, that then should sound like as if all audios would play at the same time.

I tried to use the amix filter in the last command, but it fails with "*Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_amix_0*".

```
> inputs.txt
n=0
for file in *.mp3; do
  echo "file '$file'" >> inputs.txt
  ((n++))
done

ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -filter_complex amix=inputs=$n output.mp3
```

If I manually parse the inputs files (e.g. 2 files) as follows

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -i file2.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2 output.mp3
```

the command works as intended. But I need it to work with an arbitrary amount of inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some command line tools are easier for dealing with a large amount of input files.

Using `sox`, the command is rather simple:

```
sox -m *.wav outputsox.wav
```

And here is a Bash script using `ffmpeg`, that takes audio-/video-files as input arguments, converts them to .wav-files and mixes them with amix.

```bash
inputs=()
for f in "$@"; do
  ffmpeg -i "$f" -vn -acodec pcm_s16le "${f%.*}.wav"
  inputs+=("-i" "${f%.*}.wav")
done
ffmpeg "${inputs[@]}" -filter_complex amix=inputs=$# output.mp3
```